# How to test Chrome onUpdateAvailable in extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I wanted to test onUpdateAvailable event in chrome extension.
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-requestUpdateCheck

I have tried updating the maniefest version but it didn't work.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify ["update_url"](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/autoupdate#update_url) in your manifest file which is mapped to your local server and change it when you need.

The URL should be a link to an XML document, you can check example [here](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/autoupdate#update_manifest).